# Calculate $P(X>10)$ where $X$ have Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

Calculate $P(X>10)$ where $X$ have Poisson distribution $Poisson(7,2)$. using $R$

**My attempt**
By the theory of probability we know $P(X>10)=1-P(X\leq 10)$

Then using R, the probabilitity is:

```
1-ppois(10,2,lower.tail = TRUE)
```

But i have the doubt:

```
1-qpois(10,2)
```

What is the difference?

> Moreover, i need calculate $P(2\leq X\leq 8)$

I think in this

```
sum(qpois(2:8,2))
```

is correct this? thanks

Comment: why your Poisson distribution has two parameters 7 and 2?

Comment: I don't know why exactly. I suppose is an error. Because he say with distribution $P(7,2)$ @user158565

Comment: Maybe you need to resolve this confusion first. I did not see this kind of Poisson distribution. Maybe it is 7.2?

Comment: @user158565 - In many countries, e.g., European countries and almost all of South America, the comma is used where the period is used in the U. S. (https://brilliantmaps.com/decimals/); that would be my guess here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that qpois’s output is a quantile, ppois gives a probability.

Seems you’re looking for a probability, so the first formula is OK.

For the second question, you might use ppois(8,lambda) - ppois(1,lambda) where lambda is the parameter of your variable.

Comment: ppois(8,lambda) - ppois(2,lambda), you exclude 2 or 8 (one of them). But $P(2\leq X\leq 8)$ require to keep both 2 and 8.

Comment: @user158565 thanks for the remark, I ve edited the answer